# How to view Arabic text on PDF digital signature appearance correctly using iText Sharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, itext7, appearance

I am trying to sign a PDF file using a certificate that its subject name in Arabic. Signature appearance doesn't show text correctly, the text direction should be RTL. For example, instead of "عربي" it appears "ي ب ر ع"

```
 PdfFont fontTest = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Tahoma.ttf"), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
PdfString pdfString = new PdfString("Digitally signed by\n " + cert.IssuedTo + "\n Date:" + DateTime.Now);
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
                        
appearance.SetReuseAppearance(false)
          .SetPageRect(rect)
          .SetPageNumber(pageNmber)
          .SetLayer2Font(fontTest)
          .SetLayer2Text(pdfString.ToString())
                            .SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION) ;
```

Comment: Are you using pdfCalligraph add-on?

Comment: When i used itext version 5 it worked, I don't know why this issue appears in itext 7.

Comment: Yep, but are you using pdfCalligraph (https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfcalligraph/) add-on?

Comment: No i don't use it.

Comment: In this case the behavior is expected because in iText 7 there is a separate add-on that facilitates complex script support (Arabic script is considered complex, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout)

Answer (score 1):

In iText 7 there is a separate add-on that facilitates complex script support. To enable support for [complex scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout) in iText 7, use [iText pdfCalligraph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfcalligraph/) add-on